# Does ピンク use a な-particle?

Tags: particles, adjectives

Page 82 of Fluent Forever's "Awesome Word List" for Japanese says that ピンク is a noun or a な-adjective. However, [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF) says it's a の-adjective, and I recall hearing elsewhere that it is a の-adjective. I tried checking Wiktionary, but neither the English-language nor Japanese-language editions mentioned what particle it uses.

As a general side-question, do words either only use な or only use の, or do some words sometimes use either of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's basically a の-adjective (or a noun). However, when the "pink" means atmosphere (which is "horny" or simply "happy"), not a substantial color, it can be a na-adjective. e.g ピンクな雰囲気に包まれた