# Why is な being used between two nouns?

Tags: parsing, nouns, na-adjectives

I was watching a dorama and there was an introduction sentence with な between two nouns, as if the first noun was actually a na-adjective.

> 「大学３年。彼氏なんてもちろんいない。思い切って私らしくない変身をしたハロウイン…。ハロウインの夜、残り物**な**私。」

That last sentence was actually written in the screen, so it's not even about being able to distinguish の of な. Is that a typo or a different use of な?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

残り物の私 is the standard way to say this. 残り物な私 is not a typo, but a nonstandard yet somewhat humorous way of saying the same thing. I don't think there is a name for this rhetorical technique where an ordinary noun is temporarily employed as a na-adjective, but it's a tactic you'll occasionally see in creative writing. Essentially, this is done to make a phrase sound informal, interesting and/or humorous by using words in a slightly unconventional way.

Similar examples used in titles:

- ボードゲームな夜
  <sup>(ボードゲームの夜 is more "standard", but it's uninteresting)</sup>
- クレオパトラな女たち
  <sup>("Cleopatraic Women"(?) クレオパトラの女たち would mean something totally different)</sup>
- シュガーな俺
  <sup>(This title is intentionally made to be puzzling, but those who read it would notice some unique meaning is hidden)</sup>

Sometimes, employing a noun (or no-adjective) as a na-adjective can also evoke some derived meaning. For example, see [ピンクの vs ピンクな](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55889/5010) and [無垢の vs 無垢な](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55213/5010).

Answer (score 0):

Fairly obviously this is the な form of the copula, the writer treating 残り物 as a 形容動詞. What nuance that brings to the utterance only the native speakers will be able to tell you.

Comment: P.S. Standard Japanese would be, perhaps needless to say, 残り物の私.